How to redefine standard notation
In this code I would like to change the standard notation for "~":
Disable Notation "~". (* ? *)
(* Atomic proposition. *)
Parameter atom : Set.

(* We assume atomic propositions form a set with decidable equality. *)
Parameter atom_eq : forall (a b : atom), {a = b} + {a <> b}.

(* Propositional formulas *)
Inductive formula : Type :=
| f_atom : atom -> formula
| f_not  : formula -> formula
| f_imp  : formula -> formula -> formula.

Notation "~ F" := (f_not F) (at level 35, right associativity).

Unfortunately, it gives an error:
The following notations have been disabled:
Notation "~ x" := (not x) : type_scope
File "./deduct.v", line 14, characters 0-63:
Error: Notation "~ _" is already defined at level 75 with arguments constr
at level 75 while it is now required to be at level 35 with arguments constr
at level 35.


I updated my answer, adding another solution.

Is it important for you for the notation to be at level 35? The issue is that Disable Notation removes the notation from being printed/parsed, but it stays in the grammar, meaning that you cannot "shadow" it with a new notation at a completely different level.

@MevenLennon-Bertrand "but it stays in the grammar," -  and it is impossible to remove it from the grammar?

Yes, indeed. I believe the pragma is that it is reasonable to extend a grammar on the fly, but not to restrict it.

Using custom entries.
Let us define the syntax of formula and $p_2 $ be the start symbol:

custom frm_view at level 2: $ p_2 ::= p_1 \ | \ p_1 \to p_2 $
custom frm_view at level 1: $ p_1 ::= p_0 \ | \ \sim p_1 $
custom frm_view at level 0: $ p_0 ::= ( p_2 ) \ | \ A $

It can be translated into Coq:
Parameter atom : Set.

Inductive formula : Type :=
| f_atom : atom -> formula
| f_not  : formula -> formula
| f_imp  : formula -> formula -> formula.

Declare Custom Entry frm_view.
Notation "( p )" := p (p custom frm_view at level 2, in custom frm_view at level 0).
Notation "A" := (f_atom A) (A ident, in custom frm_view at level 0).
Notation "~ p" := (f_not p) (p custom frm_view at level 1, in custom frm_view at level 1).
Notation "p -> q" := (f_imp p q) (q custom frm_view at level 2, in custom frm_view at level 2).

Notation "'$' p '$'" := p (format "'$' p '$'", p custom frm_view at level 2, at level 0).

Check fun p q => f_imp (f_imp (f_not (f_atom q)) (f_not (f_atom p))) (f_imp (f_atom p) (f_atom q)).

The response for Check:
fun p q : atom => $(~ q -> ~ p) -> p -> q$
: atom -> atom -> formula


Another solution.
Disable Notation "~". (* ? *)
(* Atomic proposition. *)
Parameter atom : Set.

(* We assume atomic propositions form a set with decidable equality. *)
Parameter atom_eq : forall (a b : atom), {a = b} + {a <> b}.

(* Propositional formulas *)
Inductive formula : Type :=
| f_atom : atom -> formula
| f_not  : formula -> formula
| f_imp  : formula -> formula -> formula.

Enable Notation "~ F".
Notation "~ F" := (f_not F).
Check fun b => f_not b.
(*
fun b : formula => ~ b
: formula -> formula
*)

However, in this solution, you cannot furthermore use ~ as a negation—e.g., ~ (1 < 4) is ill-typed.
And, the level of the notation "~ _" cannot be adjusted.
Therefore, I recommend you use the first solution.

Could you explain what does p custom frm_view at level 2, in custom frm_view at level 0 mean? It does something with operators priority level, but I see 2 of them. How do they work? How to set the priority of operators: negation is stronger then implication.

@user4035 Notation "( p )" := p (p custom frm_view at level 2, in custom frm_view at level 0). allows us to print and/or parse expressions such as $(p \to q) \to p$. If there were not be the rule, Coq cannot print and/or parse expressions that must be parenthesised. p custom frm_view at level 2, in custom frm_view at level 0 means that the expression p in the parenthesis might be a compound formula. I added the explanation for the syntax for formula. Coq tries to print/parse an expression at the highest level and decreases the level if failed. This is an answer for How do they work?.

@user4035 If the level of a notation is lower, the notation has higher priority. Thus, the level of negation is lower and so negation is already stronger. This is an answer for How do they work? How to set the priority of operators: negation is stronger then implication.

Is it possible to do it with scopes? The idea of wrapping all the formulas into $...$ doesn't seem beautiful.

I'm sorry that I don't know how to remove $ ... $. @user4035

Why do you use single quotes around dollar symbol in the delimiters of our formulaes: '$'? It works for me without them.

@user4035 To eliminate the space. To print $p -> q$ rather than $ p -> q $, I used ' in format "'$' p '$'". In Notation "'$' p '$'", ' can be removed.
